# Internal error when trying to use any composer functionality

Tags: zend-framework2, composer-php, zend-studio

I'm using composer in a ZF2 PHP project in Zend Studio 10.6. I recently tried to add a depency to the project, and I received an "internal error". Since then, whenever I try to use any function, I receive the same error:

[Error msg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LwsB6.png)

"An internal error occurred during: "Package Details".
For input string: "if (defined('COMPOSER_DEV_WARNING_TIME') && $commandName !== 'self-update' && $commandName !== 'selfupdate' && time() > COMPOSER_DEV_WARNING_TIME""

The search function when I try to add a depency also does no longer find any packages, even though I have a repository installed.

I'm very grateful for any suggestions!

Comment: That looks like an error generated from composer's start up process where it checks that your version isn't too old. Have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling composer, just to make sure your version is clean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. My solution was to use the composer via the commander.
Make sure you have installed the composer (check by writing "composer -V" in your commander to see your version), then just place your dependency in your composer.json file.
For example:

```
"require" : {
"php" : ">=5.3.3",
"zendframework/zendframework" : "=2.3.7",
```

Run the command: "composer update" in your project.
For me this worked.
You can use all composer functions in the commander.
You can find help here if you use Ubuntu: [How to install and Use Composer on Ubuntu](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-composer-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Comment: yeah, I've switched to using it form the command line. I will have to re-install Composer to use it form the IDE again, I think.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but it's a simple fix. This error basically means that ZS/Eclipse cannot find the composer.phar file. Ensure it is referenced properly in your system path, or within the IDE and 'Update Dependencies' will work just fine.